# How do I ask all of the questions in the list without repeating the lines of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
question = ["1 – Which seven-a-side ball game is played in a swimming pool?",
"2 - When was the Olympics last held in London?",
        "3 - What is the world record time of the men's 100m sprint?",
        "4 - The latest Bond song was sung by whom?",
        "5 - Who won the Euro 2016 Final?",
        "6 - Who is the mascot of Pokemon?",
        "7 - How many stars are on the U.S flag?",
        "8 - If 1 = 5, 2 = 10, 3 = 15 and 4 = 20, what does 5 =?",
        "9 - In a right angled triangle one side is 3 and another side is 4, what is the length of the hypotenuse?",
        "10 - What is the 7th decimal place of pi?"]
multi1 = ["A: Marco Polo","A: 1944","A:9.58seconds","A: Charlie Puth","A: Portugal","A: Mew","A: 49","A: 25","A: 2","A: 4"]
multi2 = ["B: Polo","B: 2004","B: 9.68seconds","B: Sam Smith","B: Wales","B: Mewtwo","B: 52","B: 4","B: 5","B: 1"]
multi3 = ["C: Water Polo","C: 2008","C: 9.54seconds","C: Adele","C: France","C: Pikachu","C: 51","C: 5","C: 3.5","C: 9"]
multi4 = ["D: Polo Marco","D: 2012","D: 9.60seconds","D: Daniel Craig","D: Germany","D: Togepi","D: 50","D: 1","D: 6","D: 6"]
correctAnswer = ['C','D','A','B','A','C','D','D','B','D']
valueWon = ['£0','£100','£2500','£500','£1000','£2500','£5000','£10000','£100000','£1000000']
x = input(question[0] + ' ' +multi1[0]+ ' ' +multi2[0]+ ' ' +multi3[0]+ ' ' +multi4[0])
if x == ("A","B","C"):
    print("I'm sorry that was incorrect,",correctAnswer[0],"was the correct answer, you won,",valueWon[0])
else:
    y = input("Congratulations, you won" +" " +valueWon[1]+" " +"would you like to continue, yes or no?")
if y == ("No","no"):
    exit
```

I'm making a 'who wants to be a millionaire' game and I want to ask all of the questions in the list without repeating all of the code that I have used above as it will be too lengthy and I know that there is an easier way. Thanks

Comment: look up 'while loop'.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to turn your questions into individual Class objects.

```
class Question():
    def __init__(self, id, question, answers, correct_answer):
        self.id = id
        self.question = question
        self.answers = answers
        self.correct_answer = correct_answer


question_one = Question(
    1,
    "Which seven-a-side ball game is played in a swimming pool?",
    {"1":"Marco Polo", "2":"Water Polo", "3":"Polo", "4":"Polo Marco"},
    "Water Polo"
                       )

question_list = [question_one]
for _ in question_list:
    print("Question number {0}: {1}".format(_.id, _.question))
    answer = input("{0}\n".format(_.answers))
    if _.answers[answer] == _.correct_answer:
        print("You're correct!")
```

The resulting output would be:

```
>>>Which seven-a-side ball game is played in a swimming pool?
>>>{'2': 'Water Polo', '1': 'Marco Polo', '3': 'Polo', '4': 'Polo Marco'}
>>>2
>>>You're correct!
```

And so on and so forth.  Please note that if you're in Python 2.7, you'll need to remove the quotations from the numbers in the `answers` dict.

Comment: Didn't think of turning them into class objects, this definitely helps, thanks

Comment: No problem! If it helps a significant amount, please consider checking the green arrow :P

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this is what you want. I see a lot of improvisations that can be made to the code. But still, I am presenting my answers here, for starters.

```
question = ["1 – Which seven-a-side ball game is played in a swimming pool?","2 - When was the Olympics last held in London?",
    "3 - What is the world record time of the men's 100m sprint?",
    "4 - The latest Bond song was sung by whom?",
    "5 - Who won the Euro 2016 Final?",
    "6 - Who is the mascot of Pokemon?",
    "7 - How many stars are on the U.S flag?",
    "8 - If 1 = 5, 2 = 10, 3 = 15 and 4 = 20, what does 5 =?",
    "9 - In a right angled triangle one side is 3 and another side is 4,what is the length of the hypotenuse?",
    "10 - What is the 7th decimal place of pi?"]
multi1 = ["A: Marco Polo","A: 1944","A:9.58seconds","A: Charlie Puth","A:Portugal","A: Mew","A: 49","A: 25","A: 2","A: 4"]
multi2 = ["B: Polo","B: 2004","B: 9.68seconds","B: Sam Smith","B: Wales","B: Mewtwo","B: 52","B: 4","B: 5","B: 1"]
multi3 = ["C: Water Polo","C: 2008","C: 9.54seconds","C: Adele","C: France","C: Pikachu","C: 51","C: 5","C: 3.5","C: 9"]
multi4 = ["D: Polo Marco","D: 2012","D: 9.60seconds","D: Daniel Craig","D: Germany","D: Togepi","D: 50","D: 1","D: 6","D: 6"]
correctAnswer = ['C','D','A','B','A','C','D','D','B','D']
valueWon = ['£0','£100','£2500','£500','£1000','£2500','£5000','£10000','£100000','£1000000']

for i,j in enumerate(question):
    x = input(j + '\n ' +multi1[i]+ '\n ' +multi2[i]+ '\n ' +multi3[i]+ '\n ' +multi4[i]+'\n')
    if x == ("A","B","C"):
            print("I'm sorry that was incorrect,",correctAnswer[i],"was the correct answer, you won,",valueWon[i])
    else:
            y = input("Congratulations, you won" +" " +valueWon[i]+" " +"would you like to continue, yes or no?")
            if y == ("No","no"):
                    break
```

I hope this helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks this helped, yeah it definitely had some holes in it that could have been prevented

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question simply: you could iterate over each question in the list of questions with a foreach loop.

```
for q in question:
    #do something with q, the for loop will do this for every q in your list 'question'
```

The problem with this is you don't have access to the corresponding multiple choice answers, the correct answer, or the value won easily. That is, if the loop is iterating and you're on the 2nd question, how does the for loop know to present the 2nd multiple choice answers, the 2nd correct answer, etc?

You could do:

```
for q in question:
    #set idx equal to the index number of the current question,
    #so if you're on question 3, it'll be index 2, and you can use
    #idx to grab the corresponding multiple choice answers/correct answer/etc
    idx = question.index(q)

    #have the user input an answer
    x = input(q + ' ' + multi1[idx] + ... + multi4[idx])
    if (x != correctAnswer[idx]):
        print("I'm sorry that was incorrect,",correctAnswer[idx],"was the correct answer")
    else:
        y = input("Congratulations, you won" +" " +valueWon[idx]+" " +"would you like to continue, yes or no?")
        if y == ("No","no"):
            break
```

but `enumerate` already does this for you:

```
for i, q in enumerate(question):
    #have the user input an answer
    x = input(q + ' ' + multi1[i] + ... + multi4[i])
    if (x != correctAnswer[i]):
        print("I'm sorry that was incorrect,",correctAnswer[i],"was the correct answer")
    else:
        y = input("Congratulations, you won" +" " +valueWon[i]+" " +"would you like to continue, yes or no?")
        if y == ("No","no"):
            break
```

You could (and probably should) create a class for this that way all of your data is coupled together instead of spread out over several objects. Then you would just have to iterate over the list of objects and use those in the same way.

Comment: Think you need `for i, q in enumerate(question)` looks like a simple typo

Comment: Funny thing is that i originally had `for q, i` when I went to correct you. Also had forgotten about enumerate. gonna have to use that.

Comment: Thanks for this, did not think about using enumerate but it helps, thanks